# Custom MKCircle like view outside the map view

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkcircle

I wanted to implement a custom circle like MKCircle outside a map view and it should work exactly like MKCircle.

Basically when we zoom-in the map the circle gets bigger and when zoom out the circle becomes smaller. I need that formula to apply the same on my custom circle outside the map.

I was trying something like this:

```
let newWidth = (1-self.mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta) * 414
constraintCircleViewWidth.constant = CGFloat(newWidth)
```

but this is not accurate.

Comment: if i am not wrong you are trying to minimise & maximise `MKAnnotation` image. Right?

Comment: @JatinRB yes based on the zoom level of the map, when user uses pinch gesture to zoom in and out

Comment: Just an idea: you could have a transparent `MKCircle` in your mapView and measure the size of the `MKCircleView`. Be sure to have the `MKCircle` in the visible region, otherwise the `MKCircleView` might not exist.